# Using Xcopy or other to copy similar folders within directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, exec, xcopy

I have one directory with several folders with names like 'MAPAS_10452; MAPAS_21685; MAPAS_22731' and os on...
Inside every folder I have several folders, but I just want to copy the contents of one of them, the folder 'NOVOS'.

Is it possible to use Xcopy, batch file or other option to copy just The contents of the folder I want, for evey folder 'MAPAS_XXXXX' I have ?

The result would be:
MAPAS_10452/NOVOS
MAPAS_21685/NOVOS
MAPAS_22731/NOVOS

Comment: Yes, it's possible (run `for/?` in the Command prompt to see the options), have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I've made this but it's not working: for %%f in C:\Users\user\Desktop\MapasSAAS\ do copy %%f\NOVOS\ C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\%%f\NOVOS

Comment: Check out `robocopy` --  you should not need anything else...

Answer (score 0):

1. As `for /?` help says you should put the path in parentheses.
2. Add a wildcard to enumerate the folder contents: `*`
3. Use only the name of parent folder to construct the new path: `%%~nf`
4. Check if the `NOVOS` subfolder actually exists.
5. For flexibility use `%USERPROFILE%` system variable
6. Use `xcopy /s` and add a trailing slash to the second argument to indicate it's a folder
7. [Optional] Use doubleqoutes to process file/folder names with spaces

---

```
for %%f in ("%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\MapasSAAS\*") do (
    if exist "%%f\NOVOS" (
        xcopy /s "%%f\NOVOS" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\folder\%%~nf\NOVOS\\"
    )
)
```

Comment: Your initial code didn't work, but with some slightly changes I was able to make it:                                                                                               for /D %%f in ("%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\MapasSAAS\\*") do (
if exist "%%f\NOVOS\\*" (
 xcopy /s "%%f\NOVOS\\*" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\folder\%%~nf\NOVOS\"
)
). So, many thanks for the help

Comment: Well, strictly speaking it wasn't my code as I've simply fixed the issues in your code.